# JQuery Vertical Infinite Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have been Looking For the Past two hours, Is there any jQuery plugin that does a Vertical Infinite Carousel effect? to be more specific here's the required layout:

[image: Vertical Infinite Carousel Layout]

Unfortunately I really don't have the experience nor the time to learn right now in order to achieve this by pure creation... Even just pointing me in the right direction would be Great...

Any Help Greatly Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out carouFredSel. It supports infinite carousel & has an easy to use code generator on the site.

http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven how did you go?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not maintained anymore, but it looks good and works:

All Demos:
http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3843/branches/labs/carousel/demo/index.html

Vertical:
http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3843/branches/labs/carousel/demo/vertical.html

Answer (score 0):

You need this.

> Ender-carousel is a really simple carousel plugin for Ender. You can easily build your own gallery on the top of this plugin.

[Ender Carousel](https://github.com/nemeseri/ender-carousel)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is dead.

Comment: @dynamic_cast Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/

Include the shapes file, have look at the API and set shape to "waterWheel". :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if these are appropriate but maybe check out:

Tiny Carousel

jq.carousel

amazing crousel

http://ryrych.github.io/rcarousel/

jQuery.silver_track

bx slider

Elastislide