# How can I stop divs from transforming on hover on each?

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel, css-transforms

First of all, if anyone have any better solutions and can save me the trouble, I will appreciate that.

Basically I'm trying to make a circular / elliptical  carousel (vertically). I haven't seen anything like it and I've been Googling for days. It's just not there, which is weird.

I'm trying to have elements rotate in a circle, and on hover on any element, the rotation of all elements will stop, and the hovered one will do some sort of animation like becoming bigger.

```
See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/23x7t4dq/
```

I tried a combination of pausing the transformations or the transitions but none works.

```css
.circle-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 440px;
    height: 440px;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-animation: rotation 6s linear 0s infinite normal none;
    -moz-animation: rotation 6s linear 0s infinite normal none;
    -ms-animation: rotation 6s linear 0s infinite normal none;
    -o-animation: rotation 6s linear 0s infinite normal none;
    animation: rotation 6s linear 0s infinite normal none;
}
.circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    left: 170px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.circle-container:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.circle:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px);
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px);
    background: #ff504f;
}
.circle:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(72deg) translateX(150px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(72deg) translateX(150px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(72deg) translateX(150px);
    -o-transform: rotate(72deg) translateX(150px);
    transform: rotate(72deg) translateX(150px);
    background: #ffe63d;
}
.circle:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(144deg) translateX(150px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(144deg) translateX(150px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(144deg) translateX(150px);
    -o-transform: rotate(144deg) translateX(150px);
    transform: rotate(144deg) translateX(150px);
    background: #50dc64;
}
.circle:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(216deg) translateX(150px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(216deg) translateX(150px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(216deg) translateX(150px);
    -o-transform: rotate(216deg) translateX(150px);
    transform: rotate(216deg) translateX(150px);
    background: #41c39d;
}
.circle:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(288deg) translateX(150px);
    -moz-transform: rotate(288deg) translateX(150px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(288deg) translateX(150px);
    -o-transform: rotate(288deg) translateX(150px);
    transform: rotate(288deg) translateX(150px);
    background: #4db5dc;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotation {
    from {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotation {
    from {
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes rotation {
    from {
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotation {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-container">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code here too, not just a link to fiddle

Comment: Maybe this is what you want ^^

https://jsfiddle.net/23x7t4dq/1/

Comment: It's slightly different that what I want. This one stops the animation on the container hover. Is it possible to stop it on hovering the circling elements?

Comment: This is possibly what you are looking for

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810743/jquery-vertical-infinite-carousel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hover on parent div - CSS-only solution**

```
.circle-container:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
     animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23x7t4dq/2/)

**Hover on each circle - jQuery solution:**

There is no selector for parent element, so CSS-only solution is not possible

JS

```
$(".circle").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass("paused");
});

$(".circle").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("paused");
});
```

CSS

```
.circle-container.paused {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
     animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23x7t4dq/5/)

Answer (score 2):

You can pause an animation using `animation-play-state: paused;`.

If you set the `width` and `height` of the container to `0` and use `transform-origin` to make sure the rotation goes well, the `:hover` will only be active when hovering over a child.

(Removed browser prefices for readability. Only tested in Firefox)

```css
.circle-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform-origin: 220px 220px;
  left: -220px;
  animation: rotation 6s linear 0s infinite normal none;
}
.circle-container:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  left: 170px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: transform .5s;
}
.circle:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px);
  background: #ff504f;
}
.circle:nth-child(1):hover {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) scale(2);
}
.circle:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(72deg) translateX(150px);
  background: #ffe63d;
}
.circle:nth-child(2):hover {
  transform: rotate(72deg) translateX(150px) scale(2);
}
.circle:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(144deg) translateX(150px);
  background: #50dc64;
}
.circle:nth-child(3):hover {
  transform: rotate(144deg) translateX(150px) scale(2);
}
.circle:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(216deg) translateX(150px);
  background: #41c39d;
}
.circle:nth-child(4):hover {
  transform: rotate(216deg) translateX(150px) scale(2);
}
.circle:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(288deg) translateX(150px);
  background: #4db5dc;
}
.circle:nth-child(5):hover {
  transform: rotate(288deg) translateX(150px) scale(2);
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-container">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no parent selector in CSS, the pause declaration in CSS goes like this:

```css
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused | running;
```

You have to use Javascript or the jQuery and it would look something like this:

```js
$(".circle").hover(
  function(){
    $(this).parent().css("-webkit-animation-play-state", "paused");
},
  function(){
    $(this).parent().css("-webkit-animation-play-state", "running");
});
```

Comment: You might want to remove your `snippet` declarations, since there is nothing runnable ;)